# Find the line count of CSV data files using Beanshell preprocess in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My requirement  is i want to use one ThreadGroup and Two CSV data files(data file1 contains lets say 1000 siteurls and datafile two contains 1500 siteurls) i want to stop the jmeter test after hitting 100 and 150 siteurls 
Creating two thread groups(1 thread each) and assigning the loop count as 1000 and 1500 is working fine i am able to stop the test after completion of exaclty one iteration of data set
But here i want to implement the same with only one thread group of 5 users how i can achieve this....

Thanks in Adavance..

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code in Beanshell PreProcessor:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; // necessary import

int lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/csv.file")).size(); // get lines count
vars.put("lines", String.valueOf(lines)); // store the count into "lines" variable
```

It uses [FileUtils.readLines()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)) method to read file contents into set of strings and gets its size and [JMeterVariables.put()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to store extracted value into "lines" variable.

You can access lines count as `${lines}` where required.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter, comprehensive explanation of pre-defined variables and a form of Beanshell cookbook.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri it works now..In bean shell preprocess is there any way to read the lines of CSV data file and put into an array ..Please help on this..

Comment: `FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/csv.file"))` reads the file into array of strings